# libssh2 version 1.2.9 or higher required for set_timeout support

Tags: windows, perl, windows-7, libssh2

I am trying to use [`Net::SSH2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2) in the following the Perl code, but I am getting this error

> libssh2 version 1.2.9 or higher required for set_timeout support at test.pl line 8.
>   1.2.566053SSH-2.0-libssh2_1.2.5
>   Press any key to continue . . .

```
use strict;

use Net::SSH2;
#use Net::SSH2::Expect;

my $Hostname = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

my $ssh = Net::SSH2->new();

print $ssh->version();

$ssh->timeout( 10 );

#$ssh->connect( "xxxxxxxx" );
```

I can see that my libssh2 version is old. Can somebody please help me with how to upgrade the libssh2 version?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot : Windows 7

Comment: `Net::SSH2` doesn't seem to support Windows. How did you install it? I suggest that you try [Net::SSH::Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Perl) instead.

Comment: What Perl are you using? The easiest way may be to install a new version of Perl. I can confirm that the most recent version of [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html) includes `libssh-1.7.0`, and `Net::SSH2` builds and installs on it without any issue.

Comment: @Borodin : I have used cygwin

Comment: @stevieb: You're right. I tried installing `Net::SSH2` on my 5.24 Strawberry Perl and it said *Library ssh2 found in standard place*. Strawberry are pretty good!

Comment: Do you need Cygwin? Or would MinGW do? I would go for a native installation of Strawberry or possibly ActivePerl.

Comment: @Borodin I never used Windows for doing Perl coding before I found interest in writing a unit test deployment system that spans Windows and Unix, so I inherited [berrybrew](https://github.com/stevieb9/berrybrew) (a Perlbrew for Windows) so I could finagle it to make it compatible with said cross-build system. Strawberry makes things as seamless as possible when going back and forth. [Here's](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::BrewBuild) the build system, fwiw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend upgrading your version of Perl, using a native Windows application. If you install the most recent version of [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html) (5.24.1.1 at time of writing), it includes `libssh2-1.7.0`. It then allows you to successfully build, install and use [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2).

Here's the output of your code:

```
c:\>perl ssh.pl
1.7.067328SSH-2.0-libssh2_1.7.0
```

It appears as though it's been in the builds for a while, but if you're upgrading, I'd go latest and greatest.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys :)